# How to embed python expression into :s command in vim?

Tags: python, vim

I can use `\=expr` in `:s` command. For example, to convert timestamps format inplace:

```
:%s/\v<\d{10}>/\=strftime('%c', submatch(0))/g
```

---

But the functionality of built-in functions are so limited. To parse a timestamp, I'd like to use python script like this:

```
$ python
>>> import datetime
>>> d = 'Apr 11 2012'
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%b %d %Y').isoformat()
'2012-04-11T00:00:00'
```

---

How to embed this `py-expr` into `:s` command?

```
:%s/\v\w+ \d{2} \d{4}/\={?py-expr?}/g
```

Thanks!

Comment: Note: if you believe vim doc, space *may* have a special meaning and thus needs to be escaped in very-magic mode. Only 0-9, a-z, A-Z and _ ASCII characters are said explicitly to have no special meaning in this mode.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have at least vim-7.3.569 then you may do the following:

```
:python import datetime
:%s/\v\w+\ \d{2}\ \d{4}/\=pyeval('datetime.datetime.strptime(vim.eval("submatch(0)"), "%b %d %Y").isoformat()')/g
```

. If you don’t you have recent vim you can emulate pyeval in this case:

```
function Pyeval(expr)
    python import json
    python vim.command('return '+json.dumps(eval(vim.eval('a:expr'))))
endfunction
```

, then replace `pyeval` in the above code with `Pyeval`.